# How can I remove the file name from the top bar of the VS Code window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to remove the file name in the top bar? It is right next to the menu bar and I suspect that the file name is the reason why part of the menu bar is hidden (the three dots are there).

[image: screenshot of window's top bar text, and shortened menu with three dots button to see more]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in your settings.json:

```json
"window.title": " "
```

If you set it as an empty string instead of a space, it will instead display "Visual Studio Code".

Alternatively, you could be fancier and use the unicode "Zero Width Space" character (`U+200B`)

```json
"window.title": "​"
```

You can't really tell there's a character in the string above because- well- it's a space with zero width :P